# my SiteMap don't work Correctly

Tags: asp.net, sitemappath

What is this error when I use SiteMapPath . when I click One link in my webSite , this error appeared in a page . of course when I upload my website,I See this error :

The page cannot be found The page you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the error, it appears that the URLs in your **SiteMap** are not relative. For example, let's say you have a subdirectory called "Example" and a page called "test.aspx" located in that "Example" directory. This entry would produce a 404 error (page not found).

```
<siteMapNode url="Test.aspx" title="Test Page" />
```

This would be the correct siteMapNode entry:

```
<siteMapNode url="~/Example/Test.aspx" title="Test Page" />
```